# Is this prolog program in tail recursive?

Tags: prolog, tail-recursion

I would like to ask if this program is tail recursive if it is not, how do I make it tail recursive?

```
euclidsqr([], [], 0).
euclidsqr([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], ED) :-
   euclidsqr(Xs, Ys, ED1),
   ED is ED1 + (X-Y)*(X-Y).
```

Comment: No, it `(is)/2` not

Comment: i know it is not tail recursive but what you mean by false?

Comment: "false" is his user name.

Comment: haha alright i see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the corresponding tail recursive version:

```
euclidsqr(Xs, Ys, ED) :-
   euclidsqr(Xs, Ys, 0, ED).

euclidsqr([], [], ED,ED).
euclidsqr([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], ED0,ED) :-
   ED1 is ED0 + (X-Y)*(X-Y),
   euclidsqr(Xs, Ys, ED1,ED).
```